# PHP escpos Printing

Tags: php, printing, escpos

Can anyone please help?

Hi , 
Iam using "EPSON TM-T82II Receipt" to print bills.Iam using the php code

```
 <?php
   require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/Escpos.php");
 try {

 $connector = null;
  $connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("EPSON TM-T82II Receipt");
  /* Print a "Hello world" receipt" */
$printer = new Escpos($connector);
$printer -> text("Hello World!\n");
$printer -> cut();

/* Close printer */
$printer -> close();  
} catch(Exception $e) {  
echo "Couldn't print to this printer: " . $e -> getMessage() . "\n";
}   
Iam getting this error "Couldn't print to this printer: Printer
```

'EPSON TM-T82II Receipt' is not valid. Use local port (LPT1, COM1, etc)
    or smb://computer/printer notation. "

Comment: Thanks your Answer
My printer is installed in the c drive in my local system.
Can you please tell how to find the path .
I will try as you said

Comment: I even tried with LPT1 I got the below
"Warning: file_put_contents(@Hello World! VA): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\escpos\src\WindowsPrintConnector.php on line 350
Couldn't print to this printer: Failed to write file to printer at LPT1 "

Comment: Hi un2x ,
Thanks for you answer I tried smb://network-path
I got the printout

Comment: if the answer below worked for you, you're welcome to [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: How can I know my Local Port or printer's network path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do exactly as the error says - instead of `WindowsPrintConnector("EPSON TM-T82II Receipt")`, you need to use `WindowsPrintConnector("LPT1")` or `WindowsPrintConnector("smb://XXX")`, where XXX is your printer's network path.